# Error creating bean with name 'googleCredentials' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a restful spring app that connects to a MySQL database. I am deploying it in gcp appengine and the database is also a gcp sql instance. I have tested the my code locally on my machine and the application connects perfectly to the sql instance. However when I try and run the application in the appengine I get a FileNotFoundException. I have already made the necessary additions to my pom file. The full error is

```
2020-05-18 17:33:03 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:03.364  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2020-05-18 17:33:05 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:05.153  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJt
aPlatform]
2020-05-18 17:33:05 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:05.179  INFO 10 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-18 17:33:06 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:06.703  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.117  WARN 10 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.bea
ns.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'googleCredentials' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/core/GcpContextAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory met
hod failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.api.gax.core.CredentialsProvider]: Factory method 'googleCredentials' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.
FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/pigeon-276916-a62807e029a3.json (No such file or directory)
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.118  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.121  INFO 10 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.127  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.167  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.176  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.204  INFO 10 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  2020-05-18 17:33:07.218 ERROR 10 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]
2020-05-18 17:33:07 default[1]  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'googleCredentials' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/core/GcpContextAutoC
onfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.api.gax.core.CredentialsProvider]: Factory method 'googleCre
dentials' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/pigeon-276916-a62807e029a3.json (No such file or directory)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiat
e(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.R
ELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEAS
E]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]      at org.springframework.bean
s.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapabl
eBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

I have made double sure that `pigeon-276916-a62807e029a3.json` does exist in location `spring-backend/src/main/resources/pigeon-276916-a62807e029a3.json` and is referenced in my application.properties file as `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/pigeon-276916-a62807e029a3.json`

Comment: You shouldn't be referring to files in the `src/` tree because that will not be available at deploy time. Resources should be copied into the build hierarchy and referred to there.  This is normally handled by your build tool (Maven, Gradle, etc)

Comment: Thank you for that. I found that simply commenting out the `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials...` solved the issue. It was only needed to run locally on my dev machine. I am working with cloud computing for the very first time so I have no clue how all the configurations work

Comment: @ChadleyMaggott I'd recommend you to post your last comment and a solution, so you can let other people know about this configuration in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for that. I found that simply commenting out the `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials...` solved the issue. It was only needed to run locally on my dev machine. I am working with cloud computing for the very first time so I have no clue how all the configurations work

Answer (score 0):

As the OP @Chadley Maggott commented, the fix for this was only to comment the line for this authentication method, as this is only used for local environments. Whn this solution is deployed to app engine, this will use the service account configured for this app engine service